# remove keys from dict based on value example nan

Tags: python, dictionary

how can I delete the keys in a dictionary that has values nan ? with and without creating new dictionary ?

example:

```
my_dictionary = dict(
    first=float("nan"),
    second="second"
)
```

expecting:

```
{'second': 'second'}
```

```
{k:v for k,v in my_dictionary.items() if not isnan(v)}
```

does not work because isnan(v) takes only number as parameter

Comment: Take a look at [`math.isnan`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use a dict comprehension using the fact that NaN is not equal to NaN:

```
out = {k:v for k,v in my_dictionary.items() if v==v}
```

or using `math.isnan`:

```
out = {k:v for k,v in my_dictionary.items() if not isinstance(v, float) or not math.isnan(v)}
```

Output:

```
{'second': 'second'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I provide two ways.

First way is to use a condition value==value. Interestingly, NaN==NaN returns False (I know it is confusing!). I used this NaN's characteristics. (FYI, see [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values))

Second way is to check if value type is not float. Even thought its type is float, it will check second condition weather it is NaN or not using `math` module. The reason I used two condition here is `math.isnan()` can only get number type, otherwise it throw an exception.

```
import math

my_dictionary = dict(
    first=float("nan"),
    second="second"
)
print(my_dictionary)  # before
#{'first': nan, 'second': 'second'}

# Way 1
my_dictionary = {k: v for k, v in my_dictionary.items() if v == v}

# Way 2
my_dictionary = {k: v for k, v in my_dictionary.items() if (not isinstance(v, float)) or (not math.isnan(v))}

print(my_dictionary)  # after
#{'second': 'second'}
```